# Python multiline regex search between sections

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I am trying to sort data coming from an online plain text government report that looks something like this:

```
Potato Prices as of 24-SEP-2014
Idaho
 BrownSpuds
  SomeSpuds 1.90-3.00 mostly 2.00-2.50
  MoreSpuds 2.50-3.50
  LotofSpuds 5.00-6.50

Washington

RedSpuds
TinyReds 1.50-2.00
BigReds 2.00-3.50
BrownSpuds
 SomeSpuds 1.50-2.50
 MoreSpuds 3.00-3.50 
 LotofSpuds 5.50-6.50
 BulkSpuds 1.00-2.50

Long Island
SomeSpuds 1.50-2.50 MoreSpuds 2.70-3.75 LotofSpuds 5.00-6.50
etc...
```

I included the inconsistent indents and line breaks intentionally. This is a government operation.

But I need a function that can look up the price for "MoreSpuds" in Idaho, for example, or "TinyReds" in Washington. I have an inkling that this is a job for Regex, but I can't figure out how to search multiple lines between "Idaho" and "Washington".

EDIT: Adding the following difficulty. A particular item isn't always present in a given state. For example, "RedSpuds" in Washington might go out of season before "RedSpuds" in another state. I need the search to end before it reaches the next state, giving me no price at all, if the item isn't listed.

I also just ran into a case where the prices were written in a paragraph instead of a list. Sort of like the last example, but the actual product names are a lot longer, such as "One baled 10 5-lb sacks sz A 10.00-10.50" so some of the names get split between lines, meaning there might be a newline anywhere in the middle of the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DOTALL modifier `(?s)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) to make dot to match even new line characters also.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """Potato Prices as of 24-SEP-2014
... Idaho
...  BrownSpuds
...   SomeSpuds 1.90-3.00 mostly 2.00-2.50
...   MoreSpuds 2.50-3.50
...   LotofSpuds 5.00-6.50
... 
... Washington
... 
... RedSpuds
... TinyReds 1.50-2.00
... BigReds 2.00-3.50
... BrownSpuds
...  SomeSpuds 1.50-2.50
...  MoreSpuds 3.00-3.50 
...  LotofSpuds 5.50-6.50
...  BulkSpuds 1.00-2.50
... 
... Long Island
... SomeSpuds 1.50-2.50 MoreSpuds 2.70-3.75 LotofSpuds 5.00-6.50"""
```

To get the price of `MoreSpuds` in `Idaho`,

```
>>> m = re.search(r'(?s)\bIdaho\n*(?:(?!\n\n).)*?MoreSpuds\s+(\S+)', s)
>>> m.group(1)
'2.50-3.50'
```

To get the price of `TinyReds` in `Washington`,

```
>>> m = re.search(r'(?s)\bWashington\n*(?:(?!\n\n).)*?TinyReds\s+(\S+)', s)
>>> m.group(1)
'1.50-2.00'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uV3bE4/1)

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `(?s)` DOTALL modifier.
- `\b` Word boundary which matches between a word and non-word character.
- `Washington` City name.
- `\n*` Matches zero or more new line characters.
- `(?:(?!\n\n).)*?` This negative lookahead within a non-capturing group asserts that match any but not of a `\n\n`(a blank line). `?` after the `*` forces the regex engine to do a shortest possible match.
- `TinyReds` Product name.
- `\s+` Matches one or more space characters.
- `(\S+)` Following one or more non-space characters are captured into group 1.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I forgot to also mention that sometimes a given item will no longer be listed under a state, red potatoes go out of season in Minnesota sooner than they do in Washington, for example. How do I make sure a search ends before reaching the next state?

Comment: A state must be preceded by a starting anchor or a blank line, Thus we ensure that the search ends before reaching the next state.